# Thermodynamics and Gibbs energy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, physical-chemistry, symmetry-breaking, quantum-chemistry

The equation for the Gibbs free energy is: $\Delta G = \Delta H - T\Delta S.$

- $\Delta H$ is the amount of energy difference between the initial state (characterized by $U_{i}$, $S_{i}$, and $V_{i}$) and the  final state ($U_{f}$, $S_{f}$, $V_{f}$).
- $T\Delta S$ is the amount of heat that is transferred to change the entropy of a system from $S_{i}$ to $S_{f}$. (Because $S$ is a state function, the change in entropy can be calculated by either a reversible process or irreversible process.)

Therefore, if the amount of energy difference between 2 states of a system  is smaller than the amount of heat used to change system's entropy reversibly, the transition is spontaneous and vice versa.

I wonder whether my understanding is right or not? Are there any intuitions to explain above?

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice intuition around the Gibbs Free Energy which, via the second law of thermodynamics, implies its usefulness to lab-based chemistry.

The Gibbs potential is defined
$$
G = U + p V - T S
$$
so its differential is
$$
dG = dU + p dV + V dP - T dS - S dT.
$$
It's usefulness is for systems held at constant pressure and temperature, e.g., for chemistry performed on an open lab bench at atmospheric pressure and room temperature.  In that case, for all thermodynamic transitions we would have $dT = dp =0$, so a thermodynamic system (e.g., our chemical reaction vessel) would have:
$$
dG = dU + p dV - T dS
$$
Separately, we could ask how the entropy of the entire universe (our "system" plus the "reservoir" of everything else) changes in a thermodynamic transitions. That is:
$$
S_{\rm tot} = S_{\rm sys} + S_{\rm res} \quad \rightarrow \quad dS_{\rm tot} = dS_{\rm sys} + dS_{\rm res}
$$
but because the total energy, $U_{\rm tot} = U_{\rm sys} + U_{\rm res}$, is conserved ($dU_{\rm tot} = 0$), and any change in volume of the system will be accounted for as an opposite change in the reservoir's volume ($dV_{\rm res} = - dV_{\rm sys}$), we find that:
$$
dS_{\rm tot} = dS_{\rm sys} + \frac{1}{T} \left[ dU_{\rm res} + p dV_{\rm res} - \sum_n \mu_{{\rm res},n}\, dN_{{\rm res},n} \right] = dS_{\rm sys} + \frac{1}{T} \left[-dU_{\rm sys} - p dV_{\rm sys}\right]
$$
where we have also assumed no chemical changes in the reservoir ($\sum_n \mu_{{\rm res}, n} \,dN_{{\rm res}, n} = 0$), so
$$
dS_{\rm tot} = - \frac{1}{T} \left[ dU_{\rm sys}  + p dV_{\rm sys} - T dS_{\rm sys} \right] = - \frac{1}{T} dG_{\rm sys}.
$$
Thus we see that changes in the entropy of the universe are proportional to changes in the Gibbs Free energy of the system (our particular chemical reaction on the lab bench), under these conditions of constant temperature and pressure.  By the Second Law of Thermodynamics, $S_{\rm tot}$ will tend to a maximum and therefore the Gibbs Free energy will tend to a minimum.  Chemists catalog the change in Gibbs free energy of certain combinations of elements to determine which reactions will proceed spontaneously at standard temperature and pressure conditions and which will not.

Comment: But is my understand is right or not ?

Comment: I do understand about the spontaneous but I wsnt to know about what is the meaning of each part in the Gibbs function. ? Thank you so much !